# how to change the value of a cell when I choose a value in another

Tags: angular6, ag-grid-angular

im currently using ag-grid in my aplication under angular 6 and my problem is:
I have a row with 3 columns, `| A | B | C |`

`A` is a select with some names
when I select a value in the row `A`, I want `B` and `C` (of the same row) change their values based on a date from `A`.

`A = { id:number , aStart:Date, aEnd:Date }`

I tried to use startEditingCell and other ways buts no one works.

Which is the right way to do that?

```
export interface Delivery {
    id: number;
    deliveryCode: string;
    startPeriodDate: Date;
    endPeriodDate: Date;
    description: string;
    inactive: boolean;
}

export class lineColumn {
    deliveryid: number
    startDate: Date
    endDate: Date
}
```

```
const columns = {
                headerName: 'Delivery',
                colId: 'delivery',
                field: 'id',
                editable: this.isGridEditableOnCondition,
                cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
                cellRenderer: this.deliveryFormatter.bind(this),
                cellEditorParams: (params) => {
                    return {
                        values: this.deliveries.map((delivery) => delivery.id),
                        formatValue: this.deliveryFormatter.bind(this),
                        displayPropertyName: 'deliveryCode',
                        valuePropertyName: 'deliveryCode',
                        displayFormat: 'deliveryCode',
                    };
                },
                onCellValueChanged: (params) => {
                    // when this value changes, the other 2 columns must change with the values of dates that delivery has (but can be still editables)
                    params.api.refreshCells();
                },
            },
            {
                headerName: 'Shipping Start Date',
                colId: 'shippingStartDate',
                field: startDate,
                editable: this.isGridEditable,
                valueFormatter: this.uiService.dateFormatter,
                cellEditor: 'atrDate',
            },
            {
                headerName: 'Shipping End Date',
                colId: 'shippingEndDate',
                field: endDate,
                editable: this.isGridEditable,
                valueFormatter: this.uiService.dateFormatter,
                cellEditor: 'atrDate',
            },
```

Comment: Please provide some code. We need to see how these values are selected, what code is trying to change the values, and what happens when it is working. Give us something to work with so we can help you debug / come up with a solution

Comment: I already done! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally:

```js
 onCellValueChanged: (params) => {

                        const api: agGrid.GridApi = params.api;
                        const delivery = this.masterdata.deliveries.find((d: Delivery) => d.deliveryId === params.newValue);
                        api.getRowNode(params.node.rowIndex).setDataValue('shippingStartDate', delivery.startPeriodDate);
                        api.getRowNode(params.node.rowIndex).setDataValue('shippingEndDate', delivery.endPeriodDate);

                        api.refreshCells();
                    }
                },
```